# WordPress menu select list dropdown capped to 10 items

Tags: php, wordpress, macos, .htaccess

Scratching my head at an issue with a WordPress install.

Basically I require to have lots of menus in the Appearance -> Menus area of WordPress, which in theory is a very normal thing to do. However, for some reason the list of menus caps at `10` items.

[image]

When I *"create a new menu"* it adds perfectly okay into the `wp_terms` table in the database but does not appear in the dropdown in the admin.

I have done/tried the following:

1. Ensured there is no errors or warnings
2. Freshly installed WordPress
3. Updated `max_input_vars` to `5000` in my `php.ini` file.
4. Set the posts limit in WordPress settings to `15`
5. Added some config to the .htaccess file also `php_value max_input_vars 5000`
6. Tried installing a separate `php.ini` file in the `wp-admin` folder
7. Deactivated all plugins.
8. Activated WordPress base theme

Has anyone faced something similar? and can any hero let me know anything I can do to fix my issue.

I am running OSx and running the built in apache local server. Even when I try put the install online on a very basic Linux server the problem still persists, even with the above steps.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can take a little time to help.

Comment: I have a little test blog I use for play.  Just added extra test menus to total 12 and they all display in the Appearance -> Menus drop down. http://cherylvelez.com/menu-ss.png  I am running Wordpress version 4.8.1  At the least it means on a default installation (i.e. no customizations), the dropdown allows more than 10 items.

Comment: Which plugins are used by you in the website.

Comment: @CherylVelez Thanks for the info, I am running the newest version of WordPress, It may be worth activating the 2017 base theme and testing.

Comment: @Aki I have tried doing this process with all plugins deactivated.. still no luck :(

Comment: let's try with .htacess

Comment: @CherylVelez I have tried activating the base WordPress theme and still no luck, still only pulls 10 in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:** Right guys, so the above steps I outlined would definitely be worth doing if you are facing this issue, however my issues were down to misconfiguration within the database, how this happened is beyond me, but...

The `wp_terms` table field `term_id` and `wp_term_taxonomy` table field `term_taxonomy_id` were not set to **auto_increment**.

The values inserted okay in the `wp_terms` table but failed to insert and assign to type of **nav_menu** correctly in `wp_term_taxonomy` table as this table couldn't assign a `term_taxonomy_id` correctly to link the two tables.

Hope this thread helps anyone who is facing a similar issue!

:)

Answer (score 0):

**1) Editing the .htaccess file.** The first method you could try is to edit the .htaccess file which is stored in the home directory of your WordPress installation. You’ll have to connect to your FTP account using some FTP client like FileZilla. Once you connected, open .htaccess file and add the following code snippet:

php_value max_input_vars 5000

From here you can increase the max_input_vars limit from 1000 to 5000, which will allow your menu items limit in WordPress to increase automatically. You can also try to increase the value from 5000 to 7000 or more if the limitations persist, however – another reason they may persist is because the PHP server is not responding to your code entry, and in that case you could try to use the solution number two.

Comment: As mentioned above I have already tried with `.htaccess` but had no luck at all :( I have played with the settings quite a lot also!

Comment: could you share the details of website?

Comment: sorry I cannot share those details, thanks ever so much for your efforts though, much appreciated.